# How to send weather info from server to an html text area box?

Tags: javascript, html, express

I just started using expressJS to create local server (localhost:3000). I can use javascript(e.g. file: app.js) to send to browser "Hello World", etc. My question is: How can I send information from server to a textarea of an html page?

```
Here is the html file (bare bones):
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Today is Monday</h1>

    <label for="weather">Weather today:</label>

    <textarea id="weather" name="weather"
              rows="5" cols="33">
    </textarea>


    <script>
      src = "app.js";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const query = req.body.cityName;
  const apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  const unit = "metric";
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + query + "&appid=" + apiKey + "&units=" + unit;

  https.get(url, function(response){
    console.log(response.statusCode);

    response.on("data", function(data){
      const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);
      const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
      const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
      const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
      const humidity = weatherData.main.humidity;
      const imageURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png";
      res.write("<p>The weather is currently " + weatherDescription + "<p>");
      res.write("<h1>The temperature in " + query + " is: " + temp + " Celcius</h1>");
      res.write("<img src=" + imageURL +">");
      res.write("<p>Humidity is: " + humidity + "<p>");
      res.send();
    });
  });
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: you can fetch it from the server and display it then in your textarea

Comment: If weather api requests are made directly from browser there is no comparison to what you are asking

Comment: which weather api would you like to use?

Answer (score 1):

### Fetch Data From The Server

If this is one of your endpoints in your express js app

**index.js**

```
app.get('/API/getData', (req, res) => {
        let text = "Hello World";
        res.end(text);
   
})
```

Then you can fetch the data from the server with

```
let res = await fetch('/API/getData')

let data = await res.text();
```

**bla.html**

```
<textarea id="txar"></textarea>
<script> 
async function getData(){
let res = await fetch('/API/getData')

let data = await res.text();
return data;
}
getData().then((data) => {
document.getElementById('txar').innerHTML = data;
});

</script>
```

Comment: Multiple issues with this code....typos, incorrect method setting value and not using `async` when using `await`. You might want to test it yourself first